# Syslog flooded with messages: dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.11.1 port 67

Tags: dhcp

My syslog is filled with:

```
Jun 27 10:20:08 pi dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.11.1 port 67
Jun 27 10:20:19 pi dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.11.1 port 67
Jun 27 10:20:30 pi dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.11.1 port 67
Jun 27 10:20:42 pi dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.11.1 port 67
Jun 27 10:20:53 pi dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.11.1 port 67
Jun 27 10:21:01 pi dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.11.1 port 67
Jun 27 10:21:10 pi dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.11.1 port 67
Jun 27 10:21:20 pi dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.11.1 port 67
Jun 27 10:21:37 pi dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.11.1 port 67
Jun 27 10:21:58 pi dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.11.1 port 67
Jun 27 10:22:10 pi dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.11.1 port 67
Jun 27 10:22:25 pi dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.11.1 port 67
Jun 27 10:22:44 pi dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.11.1 port 67
Jun 27 10:23:03 pi dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.11.1 port 67
Jun 27 10:23:19 pi dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.11.1 port 67
Jun 27 10:23:36 pi dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.11.1 port 67
Jun 27 10:23:57 pi dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.11.1 port 67
Jun 27 10:24:09 pi dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.11.1 port 67
Jun 27 10:24:20 pi dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.11.1 port 67
Jun 27 10:24:29 pi dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 192.168.11.1 port 67
```

I have googled and whilst there are many posts, out of all the various solutions I've tried, nothing helped so far.

For what it's worth, this is a wired only connection and resolvconf is installed. It's a Pi 2 Model B.

PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"

Answer (score -1):

I "fixed" this, by assigning a fixed IP to the RPi's MAC address in the router.